# React.js onChange make the parent aware of the changed state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent, onchange

I have a component that is rendering `<select>` with `<option>` elements. When any change occurs, I would like to change the state of the component to keep the value of the currently selected option. As far as I know I don't have any other alternative for keeping this value since the props in React JS have to be immutable.

The problem comes when I notify the parent for the change. I do this using a callback from `handleChange` to parent's `handleChange`function. So in the child element I actually call the `handleChange`function, set the new state and call the callback (parent's `handleChange`). But then in the parent function when I ask for the value of the state property I receive the older one (seems like the new one is still not set).

So any ideas?

Comment: need code.......... *In zombie voice*

Comment: I prefer more theoretical approach to the question that's why I didn't post any code. Otherwise all kind of non working solutions may be suggested.

Comment: I think you will find that if you can reduce your problem down to a very basic example (and present it with your question) you will receive much better answers than otherwise.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a single data flow pattern (like [Flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux) or [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs)) to structure your react apps and avoid that kind of mistake and complicated reverse data flows.

From what I understood of your question, without Flux, you could do something like this.

```
var React = require("react");

var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(newOption){
        console.log("option in child component changed to " + newOption);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            selectedOption: 0
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(){
        var option = this.refs.select.getDOMNode().value;
        this.setState({ selectedOption: option});
        // I'm passing the actual value as an argument,
        // not this.state.selectedOption
        // If you want to do that, do it in componentDidUpdate
        // then the state will have been set
        this.props.handleChange(option);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>My Select</h4>
                {this.state.selectedOption}
                <select ref="select"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

**Edit**
Added a couple of forgotten semi-colons. I'm coding too much Python these days.

**Edit2**
Changed the code. Your problem might be that if you call the parent's handleChange with the value from the state (`this.state.selectedOption`), the state won't be set yet so you have to give the actual value as an argument instead. If you really want to use `this.state.selectedOption`, call parent's `handleChange` in [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate).

Comment: This actually works when I don't pass the whole component to the parent (trying to get the state) but only the value. But in this context I have another question. Isn't it correct to save the current selected value as the state of the component?

Comment: Edited my answer. I just misunderstood where you needed to keep the current state